# InjectorJob: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation (gora solr, nutch 2)

Tags: hadoop, solr, nutch

I need some help with apache nutch 2.3.1. 
With hbase 0.94 everything works ok but when i setup for solrStore I get this erors.

```
InjectorJob: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by theDistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getScheme(FileSystem.java:214) at 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2365) at 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2375) at 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2392) at 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:89) at 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2431) at 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2413) at 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:368) at 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:167) at 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:352) at 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.addInputPath(FileInputFormat.java:372) at 
org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:212) at 
org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:252) at 
org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:275) at 
org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70) at 
org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:284)
```

Here are some of the steps I did

- **solr**: have solr 4.8.1 with webpage schema (no errors)
- **ivy.xml**: uncommented dependency name="gora-solr" rev="0.5"
- **nutch-site.xml**: org.apache.gora.solr.store.SolrStore
- **gora.properties**

  ```
  gora.datastore.default=org.apache.gora.solr.store.SolrStore
  gora.solrstore.solr.url=http://localhost:8983/solr
  gora.solrstore.solr.config=solrconfig.xml
  gora.solrstore.solr.schema=gora-solr-webpage-schema.xml
  gora.solrstore.solr.batchSize=100
  gora.solrstore.solr.solrjserver=http
  gora.solrstore.solr.commitWithin=1000
  gora.solrstore.solr.resultsSize=100
  ```
- ant runtime

Did someone managed to use gora solr 0.5 with apache nutch 2.3?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Solr is working perfectly and I've added the correct schema.xml file to the collection but I still get the same error that suspiciously mentions hadoop when you'd expect to see solr.